# Replace numeric part of string with addition

Tags: r, regex

I have a large list with more than 100 elements. I would like to add 200 to the ID.

```
var <- c("ID66Session1_Date-2017-02-28__10-38.csv","ID66Session2_Date-2017-03-04__21-31.csv","ID66Session3_Date-2017-03-07__19-17.csv",
         "ID66Session4_Date-2017-03-09__18-08.csv","ID66Session5_Date-2017-03-15__16-26.csv","ID66Session6_Date-2017-04-15__23-39.csv",
         "ID6Session1_Date-2017-01-20__11-06.csv")

aim <- c("ID266Session1_Date-2017-02-28__10-38.csv","ID266Session2_Date-2017-03-04__21-31.csv","ID266Session3_Date-2017-03-07__19-17.csv",
         "ID266Session4_Date-2017-03-09__18-08.csv","ID266Session5_Date-2017-03-15__16-26.csv","ID266Session6_Date-2017-04-15__23-39.csv",
         "ID206Session1_Date-2017-01-20__11-06.csv")
```

I believe it's possible to solve this with grepl. But other solutions are also welcomed. I am looking for a handy and short code.

Comment: What is the range of the original ID's? Maybe from 1 to 99?

Comment: The range is 1 to 150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsubfn` is exactly for that:

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("((?<=ID)\\d+)", function(x, ...) as.numeric(x) + 200, var, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "ID266Session1_Date-2017-02-28__10-38.csv" "ID266Session2_Date-2017-03-04__21-31.csv"
# [3] "ID266Session3_Date-2017-03-07__19-17.csv" "ID266Session4_Date-2017-03-09__18-08.csv"
# [5] "ID266Session5_Date-2017-03-15__16-26.csv" "ID266Session6_Date-2017-04-15__23-39.csv"
# [7] "ID206Session1_Date-2017-01-20__11-06.csv"
```

As to avoid constructing a replacement value by "ID" + (200 + ID value) + "Session...", we use a positive lookbehind: If there is "ID" right behind us, we take all the subsequent digits. Those are then converted to a number and 200 is added.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `stringr` and `purrr`

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
map_chr(map(str_split(var, "(?<=ID)"), function(x)
    unlist(str_split(x, "(?=Session)"))), function(y)
        paste0(y[1], as.numeric(y[2]) + 200, y[3]))
#[1] "ID266Session1_Date-2017-02-28__10-38.csv"
#[2] "ID266Session2_Date-2017-03-04__21-31.csv"
#[3] "ID266Session3_Date-2017-03-07__19-17.csv"
#[4] "ID266Session4_Date-2017-03-09__18-08.csv"
#[5] "ID266Session5_Date-2017-03-15__16-26.csv"
#[6] "ID266Session6_Date-2017-04-15__23-39.csv"
#[7] "ID206Session1_Date-2017-01-20__11-06.csv"
```

Explanation: We split `var` into three parts using a positive look-behind and look-ahead: part 1 ending in `ID`, part 2 between (and excluding) `ID` and `Session` (i.e. the relevant part containing the ID number), and part 3 starting with `Session`. We then convert the middle part `as.numeric` and add 200 before concatenating all three parts.